# FastAPI - after successful login, no Authorization header received, also from Swagger and only when deployed on server

Tags: python, docker, oauth-2.0, swagger, fastapi

My FastAPI works in my localhost, but when deployed on a server the following happens:

Login succeeds and token is retrieved from the response.

After the successful login, any API call requiring the dependency oauth2_scheme, raise error 401, including from Swagger.
Debugging the issue, there is no Authorization header in the request from the client, although it's sent. This only happens in the server deployment (both Linux or Windows), in localhost everything works.

Therefore the following call works in my localhost, and doesn't in the server.

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://url/me' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer token_received_from_successful_login'
```

The error is raised when calling the Depends(oauth2_scheme):

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/login")
```

For example, the path http:/url/me below returns the user when my FastAPI is deployed locally (localhost), but returns 401 when it's deployed on a server.

```
@app.get("/me", response_model=User)
async def who_am_I(current_user: User = Depends(get_user_from_jwt)):
    return current_user


async def get_user_from_jwt(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        if not token: # tested with auto_error=False
            return None

        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username = payload.get("sub")
        email = payload.get("email")
        if username is None:
            print("Error in token decoding")
            raise credentials_exception
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    return User(**{
        'username': username,
        'email': email
    })
```

The problem is raised inside the oauth2_scheme, when calling get_user_from_jwt.

I am launching the API using Gunicorn server with 4 Uvicorn workers.

Both localhost and server deployments are exactly the same, absolutely no difference in installed packages, python packages versions, etc...

Tested in Linux and Windows servers, full server setup or using containers, same issue.

Debugging with PyCharm on the Windows server I see that there is no Authorization header in the request received from clients (including Swagger after successful login), and this raises error 401.

[image: No Authorization header received]

But Swagger and other clients do send the Authorization header.
And the same API successfully works in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the cause was a hard-to-find network setting that was dropping the auth header from http requests, totally unrelated with FastAPI.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Between the frontend and the FastAPI server, there was a network rule that removed the authorization header: 'authorization': 'bearer token'. This is why everything worked well when client and FastAPI were both in localhost, but not when FastAPI was deployed on the server.